# index/glossaryディレクティブでのデータの取り込み処理で、conf.pyの設定値を使う方法。

Tags: python3, sphinx

Sphinx拡張を実装する際のパラメータ値の使い方についての質問です。
よろしくお願いします。

■質問
index/glossaryディレクティブでのデータの取り込み処理で、conf.pyの設定値を使う方法。

■備考
現状は次のように考えており、対応策もありますしダメ元な質問です。

- 方法はない。
- 次のように対処する：

  1. データの受入処理では、データの取り込みだけに留める
  2. 表示する直前で、設置値が必要な処理を行う

■背景
index/glossaryディレクティブでの単語/用語について、読み仮名情報を付与する拡張を作りました。
読み仮名情報及びルビ表示指定の情報を付与するに当たって「r'|'」「r'^'」をメタ文字として使っています。

念の為、これを設定により変更可能としたいのですが、ディレクティブ毎の指定ではなくconf.pyで統一的に設定する方法を実現したいと思っています。

索引ページ（genindex.html）の対応については表示処理（*1）で行われているので「self.config.{パラメータ名}」で取れるのですが、index/glossaryディレクティブ（*2,3）では「config」が見当たりません。

> 「そのためにディレクティブにはオプションがあるのか」と初めて理解しました…）

■確認したこと
*1 索引ページの表示処理の場所

- sphinx/builder/html/**init**.py
- StandaloneHTMLBuilderクラス/write_genindex()メソッド
- IndexEntries(self.env).create_index(self)の前後に処理を入れています。

*2 indexディレクティブの取り込み処理の場所

- sphinx/domains/index.py
- IndexDirectiveクラス/run()メソッド
- 「config」「cfg」という文字列がないことを確認

*3 glossaryディレクティブの取り込み処理の場所

- sphinx/domains/std.py
- Glossaryクラス/run()メソッド
- 「config」「cfg」という文字列がないことを確認

*4 その他

- glossaryディレクティブの表示処理については、HTML5Translatorクラス/visit_term()メソッドを書き換えて、ここで自前のクラスを投入しています。

  - sphinx/writers/html5.py
  - HTML5Translatorクラス/visit_term()メソッド
- 設定値の登録方法は、他の方のSphinx拡張を見てsetup()にapp.add_config_value()があることを確認しました。

以上

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reSTのdirectiveでconf.pyの設定値を参照するには以下の様に書きます。

```
class SomeDirective(SphinxDirective):
    def run(self):
        conf_val = self.config.your_config_value
```

ドキュメント
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/utils.html?highlight=config

コード
https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/56f97d71a2b1733ebf401d357a634e2d7e4c896e/sphinx/util/docutils.py#L315

Comment: 情報提供ありがとうございます。自作の拡張に組み込んで確認した上で、「承認」マークをチェックする予定です。結果に関わらず、情報は有用なので投票しました。

Comment: ソースを読んで見通しは立ちました。実装後となるとデバッグやら何やらで更に日数を要するので、「承認」マークをチェックします。ありがとうございました。